# Running Qpowertop in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, kde, power-management, qt, ubuntu-gnome

I found a graphical interface for powertop on [Google code under the name Qpowetop](https://code.google.com/archive/p/qpowertop/), I download it and so far I wasn't able to install it on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

The documentation says it's for KDE and I was wondering if it works on Gnome too? I tried running it but so far nothing.

I need help running it, so all feedback is appreciated.
[This is the download link.](https://code.google.com/archive/p/qpowertop/downloads)

When running it from a USB I got this error message: `Ubuntu unable to locate program`. Does it add to anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for KDE and there is no way to make it run on Ubuntu.